# Replace NULL with "N/A"

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to use the Oracle NVL() function to replace NULL with "N/A":

```
SELECT ID AS "Record ID",
    ( SELECT NVL( COMMENT , "N/A") FROM CHECKBOX WHERE ( B1_CHECKBOX_DESC = 'Solar KW' ) AND ( RECORDS.ID1 = CHECKBOX.ID1 AND RECORDS.ID3 = CHECKBOX.ID3 ) ) AS "Solar",
    ( SELECT NVL( COMMENT, "N/A" ) FROM CHECKBOX WHERE ( B1_CHECKBOX_DESC = 'Code Edition' ) AND ( RECORDS.ID1 = CHECKBOX.ID1 AND RECORDS.ID3 = CHECKBOX.ID3 ) ) AS "Coder"
FROM RECORDS
```

Note: I'm trying to replace NULL with "N/A," not an empty string, so it should work. However, in the result set, I'm still getting NULL values instead of "N/A". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add a couple of rows of sample data.

Comment: That may happen, for example, if COMMENT is a single space rather than NULL.

Comment: That code shouldn't compile but throw "ORA-00904: "N/A": invalid identifier" (unless you really have a column named `"N/A"`)... Use single quotes for string literals.

Comment: Is it really Oracle? Post your real query

Answer (score 1):

Just wrong place for `NVL()`, not that your subqueries may not return rows, so use NVL on subquery:

```
SELECT ID AS "Record ID",
   NVL( 
    ( SELECT "COMMENT" FROM CHECKBOX WHERE B1_CHECKBOX_DESC = 'Solar KW' 
      AND RECORDS.ID1 = CHECKBOX.ID1 AND RECORDS.ID3 = CHECKBOX.ID3 )
    , 'N/A')  AS "Solar",
   NVL( 
    ( SELECT "COMMENT" FROM CHECKBOX WHERE B1_CHECKBOX_DESC = 'Code Edition' 
      AND RECORDS.ID1 = CHECKBOX.ID1 AND RECORDS.ID3 = CHECKBOX.ID3 )
    , 'N/A' ) AS "Coder"
FROM RECORDS
```

But probably it would be better to use lateral or outer apply here:

```
SELECT
   ID AS "Record ID",
   c.*
FROM RECORDS
     outer apply(
        SELECT 
           nvl(solar,'N/A') as solar,
           nvl(coder,'N/A') as coder
        FROM (select * 
              from CHECKBOX 
              WHERE B1_CHECKBOX_DESC in ('Solar KW' , 'Code Edition')
               AND RECORDS.ID1 = CHECKBOX.ID1 
               AND RECORDS.ID3 = CHECKBOX.ID3 
             )
        pivot(
          max("COMMENT")
          for B1_CHECKBOX_DESC in (
               'Solar KW' as Solar, 
               'Code Edition' as Coder
              )
        )
     ) c
```

Full example with test data:

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4bd9c0c54e8c040569778240841c936e)

```
with
 records(id,id1,id3) as (
    select 1,1,1 from dual union all
    select 2,2,2 from dual
)
,CHECKBOX("COMMENT",id1,id3,B1_CHECKBOX_DESC) as (
    select 'comment1-1',1,1, 'Solar KW' from dual union all
    select 'comment1-2',1,1, 'Code Edition' from dual union all
    select 'comment2-1',2,2, 'Solar KW' from dual
)
SELECT
   ID AS "Record ID",
   c.*
FROM RECORDS
     outer apply(
        SELECT 
           nvl(solar,'N/A') as solar,
           nvl(coder,'N/A') as coder
        FROM (select * 
              from CHECKBOX 
              WHERE B1_CHECKBOX_DESC in ('Solar KW' , 'Code Edition')
               AND RECORDS.ID1 = CHECKBOX.ID1 
               AND RECORDS.ID3 = CHECKBOX.ID3 
             )
        pivot(
          max("COMMENT")
          for B1_CHECKBOX_DESC in (
               'Solar KW' as Solar, 
               'Code Edition' as Coder
              )
        )
     ) c;
```

Results:

```
 Record ID SOLAR      CODER
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 comment1-1 comment1-2
         2 comment2-1 N/A
```

Comment: Try it, you'll get: "ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments."

Comment: I don't get such error...

Comment: Post what exactly are you trying to run and on which oracle version